# error getting a user existing in laravel sanctum

Tags: laravel

I have a error, I'm using sanctum and I want to check that the email does not exist

the if returns an empty array but the if is satisfied because it returns true

```php
$mail = $request->input(['email']);

if ($search = User::where('email', $mail)->get()) {
    return response()->json(['msg' => 'account already exist'], 409);
} else {
    $validate = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|',
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);
}
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the Laravel validation since this looks more like validation, so something like:

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string|',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users,email',
    'password' => 'required|string'
]);
```

with this you don't need to do an if else. You can check the Laravel docs on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#introduction for more details

Comment: it's posibble return any message if the email already exits?

Comment: by default laravel returns a validation message if the user exists and you can catch these messages on your blade template

Comment: is an api rest I need return error  in any json

Comment: yeah if your request expects json, then larave retruns a 422 response with the appropriate messages